# Where does juju store its cache

Tags: juju

I'm running Juju on a node with a very small root partition. Deploying a few charms (to other machines) results in a full disk on the bootstrap machine.

- Where does Juju store the charm cache?
- What other folders on the bootstrap machine grow if you add charms?
- Can I just symlink these directories to a disk that has more space?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Juju stores the charm cache in mongodb. This is the juju version of mongodb and it stores to a database at `/var/lib/juju/db`.

A symlink of this directory to another disk is possible.

After a bootstrap of an environment I ran these commands:

```
service juju-db stop
mv /var/lib/juju/db /mnt/juju-db
ln -s /mnt/juju-db /var/lib/juju/db
service juju-db start
```

Now the database is on the filesystem mounted at /mnt.